# Changing Forecolor of ListView

Tags: listview, windows-10, listviewitem, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I really need your help, because I couldn't find a solution for my problem!

I'm developing a Universal Windows 10 app and have a timetable (ListView) in it.

Now I'd like to mark the item in the timetable, which is currently running. For Example there is an item which goes from Monday 07:00 to 13:00 and now it is Monday 12:00 so the item should change its color to red (or something) like it is marked.

I've tried several things now and that's the code so far:

First here is my xaml-Code for the ListView:

```
<RelativePanel Name="rpStundenplan">
        <ListView x:Name="lstViewStundenplan" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="lstViewStundenplan_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <RelativePanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                            <RelativePanel Name="rpTag" Width="100">
                                <TextBlock Name="txtTag" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Tag_lang}" TextWrapping="Wrap" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" />
                            </RelativePanel>
                            <RelativePanel Name="rpZeit" Width="auto" RelativePanel.Below="rpTag" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWith="rpTag">
                                <TextBlock Name="txtZeitVon" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Beginn}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Name="txtZeitBis" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Ende}" VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.RightOf="txtZeitVon" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                            </RelativePanel>
                      </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </RelativePanel>
```

I'm filling the ListView with this code:

```
    private void StundenplanAktualisieren()
    {
        //Studiengänge aus integrierter Datenbank in ListView eintragen
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection connIntern = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sPathdatabaseIntern))
        {
            var query = connIntern.Table<Classes.Stundenplan>();

            //ListBox erste leeren
            this.lstViewStundenplan.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                this.lstViewStundenplan.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

And now the code, where the error appears:

```
public void AktuelleZeit()
    {
        //markiert die aktive Vorlesung
        ListView lstView = new ListView();
        lstView = lstViewStundenplan;

        for (int i = 1; i < lstView.Items.Count; i++)
        {
                    ListViewItem Item = (ListViewItem)lstViewStundenplan.Items[i];

                    Item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
        }

    }
```

Unfortunately the line

```
ListViewItem Item = (ListViewItem)lstViewStundenplan.Items[i];
```

throws the exeption:

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'CampusAppHSHof.Classes.Stundenplan' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem'."}

I hope the code is enough for you to reproduce the problem... I tried to make it as short as possible...

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's hard to reproduce the issue. Please post a complete sample.

Comment: Hi @User0123456789! Thank you for your response! I will try my very best to edit my Question to make it Minimal, Complete and Verifiable! I'm new here and very happy for your help and don't hesitate to tell me, if I'm doing it wrong again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we don’t manipulate the ListView’s item directly, the common way is adding the items to the `ObservableCollection` and set ItemSource property of ListView to bind to the `ObservableCollection`.

According to the question, the `lstViewStundenplan.Items` gets the collection used to generate the content of the `ListView`. In your project, the item in collection is `Stundenplan` type. So you get the exeption:

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'CampusAppHSHof.Classes.Stundenplan' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem'."}

You can use [`ItemsControl.ContainerFromItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl.ContainerFromItem);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to get the container corresponding to the specified item. That you can cast it to `ListViewItem` type.

By the way, in `AktuelleZeit` method the code `ListView lstView = new ListView(); lstView = lstViewStundenplan;` semms it is redundant.

For example:

```
public void AktuelleZeit()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < lstViewStundenplan.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem Item = (lstViewStundenplan).ContainerFromItem(lstViewStundenplan.Items[i]) as ListViewItem;
        Item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jayden Gu! Thank you very much for your help! As you can imagine I'm totally new to uwp and only had a little c# in school... I guess I'll have a closer look to the Observable Collection... I tried your solution for my problem an now another error appears in the line <pre>Item.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
<code> because the item seems to be null. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: It seems there is no error in you case. I have uploaded my sample, you can download [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=53E31D9ACF7C5147!3298&authkey=!ANugVISI82emc-o&ithint=file%2czip)